# How to control user access to routes in AWS Gateway API

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm building an app that accesses data in an AWS database via AWS Gateway API HTTP API.

User must authenticate on AWS Gateway (not done yet, I think AWS Cognito can do the job) and must gain access to some API routes.

1. How to give users access to corresponding routes?

Example:

```
User A gains access to https://aws-endpoint/A/*
User B gains access to https://aws-endpoint/B/*
```

2. Is there a simple way to do it using some aws-cli commands that will create user A, give the user access to route `https://aws-endpoint/A/*` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. One option to do that is by having a custom lambda authorizer, in which you can check user details accordingly
2. Another option is to use JWT authorizer and let 3rd party identity providers(eg. Okta) manage user access based on user parameters defined.

Both of the above options can be found here: [AWS HTTPAPI Authorization](http://(ref:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-access-control.html).)

A crude way can also be to use different authorizers for different endpoints.